# ng-disabled not working properly

Tags: angularjs

I have created a directive to allow tab into a text field, Its also required. The problem is error is showing/hiding correctly but the button is not getting disabled even the form is invalid. Check the js fiddle here http://jsfiddle.net/c5omqx4t/3/

Steps to reproduce:

```
1) Select input box
2) Press Tab key
3) Press Backspace key
issue: Error is still here but the button is enabled
```

here is the html code

```
<div ng-controller="helloController">
        <h1>{{hello}}</h1>
        <form name="createForm">
            <div ng-if="providerMediumType != 'XML_API'">
            <input name="cSep" ng-model="cSep" type="text" class="form-control" allow-tab required ng-maxlength="10" />
            <p ng-show="createForm.cSep.$invalid && !createForm.cSep.$pristine" class="error">Column separator required (1-10 characters)</p>     
        </div>
            <input type="button" ng-disabled="createForm.$invalid" value="Go" />
        </form>
    </div>
```

Comment: hope you noticed that the moment you press `createForm.$invalid` becomes `false` even after the backspace it remain `false`.

Answer (score 3):

Solution 1:

Just use `ng-show` instead of `ng-if`. Because ng-if create a new scope here.

```
<div ng-controller="helloController">
        <h1>{{hello}}</h1>
        <form name="createForm">
            <div ng-show="providerMediumType != 'XML_API'">
            <input name="cSep" ng-model="cSep" type="text" class="form-control" allow-tab required ng-maxlength="10" />
            <p ng-show="createForm.cSep.$invalid && !createForm.cSep.$pristine" class="error">Column separator required (1-10 characters)</p>     
        </div>
            <input type="button" ng-disabled="createForm.$invalid" value="Go" />
        </form>
    </div>
```

[Demo link](http://jsfiddle.net/c5omqx4t/4/)

Solution 2:

or just pull input go field into inside DIV tags

[Demo link2](http://jsfiddle.net/c5omqx4t/5/)

```
<div ng-controller="helloController">
        <h1>{{hello}}</h1>
        <form name="createForm">
            <div ng-if="providerMediumType != 'XML_API'">
            <input name="cSep" ng-model="cSep" type="text" class="form-control" allow-tab required ng-maxlength="10" />
            <p ng-show="createForm.cSep.$invalid && !createForm.cSep.$pristine" class="error">Column separator required (1-10 characters)</p>   
            <input type="button" ng-disabled="createForm.$invalid" value="Go" />  
        </div>

        </form>
    </div>
```

Solution 3:

Use `controller as` syntax to acheive this. Also small changes in helloController. Note that `this.providerMediumType` instead of `$scope.providerMediumType`.

```
<body ng-app="HelloApp">
    <div ng-controller="helloController as vm">
        <h1>{{hello}}</h1>
        <form name="createForm" method="POST" action="/form.php">
            <div ng-if="vm.providerMediumType != 'XML_API'">
            <input name="cSep" ng-model="vm.cSep" type="text" class="form-control" allow-tab required ng-maxlength="10" />
            <p ng-show="createForm.cSep.$invalid && !createForm.cSep.$pristine" class="error">Column separator required (1-10 characters)</p>     

        </div>
            <input type="submit" ng-disabled="createForm.$invalid" value="Go" />

        </form>
    </div>
</body>



angular.module('HelloApp', ['components']).controller('helloController',helloController);

function helloController($scope) {
    $scope.hello = 'Hello Me!';
    this.providerMediumType = 'XML_API';    
}
```

[Demo with ng-if](http://jsfiddle.net/c5omqx4t/6/)

Comment: sorry, but cannot replace ng-if with ng-show! Otherwise on submitting form all hidden input will also posted. Any other solution here?

Comment: Updated answer could you please check.

Answer (score 0):

Found the solution. In directive use c.$apply() instead of c.$digest()