# Why does ng-disabled not work with $pristine here?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

The below HTML does not work as expected. Even when I type in the input box the button remains disabled:

```
<form name="form">
  <td>
    <input type="text" ng-if="user.saveAllowed" ng-model="user.limit">
    <p ng-if="!user.saveAllowed">{{user.limit}}</p>
  </td>
  <td ng-if="user.saveAllowed">
    <button class="btn btn-limit btn-success" ng-click='user.setLimit(user.limit)' ng-disabled="form.$pristine">Save</button>
  </td>
</form>
```

Comment: This can be because save button is in ng-if block, which completely removes DOM elements inside and looses bindings. Try to replace ng-if with ng-show.

Answer (score 0):

When I tried it worked as expected, could you check?

```js
angular.module("myApp", []).controller("myCtrl", function($scope) {
  $scope.user = {saveAllowed: true};
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<html ng-app="myApp">
<form name="form" ng-controller="myCtrl">
  <td>
    <input type="text" ng-if="user.saveAllowed" ng-model="user.limit">
    <p ng-if="!user.saveAllowed">{{user.limit}}</p>
  </td>
  <td ng-if="user.saveAllowed">
    <button class="btn btn-limit btn-success" ng-click='user.setLimit(user.limit)' ng-disabled="form.$pristine">Save</button>
  </td>
</form>

</html>
```

Comment: Hmmm, yeah that worked for me. Could it have anything to do with the fact that I'm using `controllerAs` syntax rather than `$scope`?

Comment: Hmm don't think so, but could you try that out?

Comment: Actually, reading through this makes me think it's my `ng-if`'s causing the trouble because they create new scopes: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30026114/ng-disabled-not-working-properly